# Is the word "chum" to mean friend a common word?

Tags: american-english, word-usage, vocabulary

Does the average American know its meaning? Is it used commonly in the spoken language? What connotations does it have?

Is it gender specific?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To take your questions in order, starting from the title question:

1. It's not very common. In text, since 1960,
   ['Pal', 'buddy', and 'chum' all stay relatively very low until 1990, but then 'buddy' rises fast to about 7 times as frequent by 2010 and 'pal' to 3 times as frequent.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chum%2Cbuddy%2Cpal&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

[image: NGram graph of frequencies of pal, buddy, and chum from 1960 to 2019. All stay relatively very low until 1990, but then buddy rises fast to about 7 times as frequent by 2010 and pal to 3 times as frequent]

If you modify the parameters in NGrams, you'll see that limiting to the British or American corpus doesn't change the trend much.

As an AmE speaker it sounds very Wodehousian to me, like some old guy with a monocle drinking a g and t with an old rugby mate from public school.

2. If it were spoken in context, an American would easily figure out that it is something vaguely like 'friend or pal or buddy or whatever'. But it sounds very high class British to Americans.
3. The great majority of Americans don't have it in their production lexicon. Only a very very few Masterpiece Theater watchers (exposed to older British media) might at a stretch use it tongue-in-cheek.
4. It is just as gendered as buddy/pal/mate which means it is used a) mostly b) by men, talking to c) men but d) that's not a hard rule. (that is, -if- it were to be used at all in the US)

Comment: If you adjust your nGrams chart changing "English (2019)" to "American English" or "British English", the trans-Atlantic difference does not look too great for *chum* though the *buddy/pal* gap widens in "American English"

Comment: There are some specific uses of buddy, such as in Alcoholics Anonymous and other counselling/support, the "buddy system" in some activities (diving, school trips), and specific terms such as "drinking buddy". I don't think they would be very significant for the NGram totals, as they're all quite narrow, specialized areas.

Comment: "As an AmE speaker it sounds very Wodehousian to me, like some old guy with a monocle drinking a g and t with an old rugby mate from public school." - I can assure you that 'pal' and 'chum' were widely used among the working and middle classes in the UK before World War 2. My father (born 1920) used, as a boy, to read a weekly boy's paper called 'Chums' published 1892 to 1941, and there were 'pals battalions' in the 1914 war of young men from the same towns who joined _en masse_. In the UK, 'Pal' and 'Chum' persist as brands of dog food.

Comment: I am always flummoxed by what people say about who says what in English. I say all sorts of things outside the norm, as it were. Is anyone listening? [joke]

Comment: As UkE speaker, I don't hear 'chum' as gendered.  It's definitely old fashioned, the only modern colloquial usage I come across is in the context of children. 'Did you meet your chums at the football match?' . Buddy to UkE ears is very American in the friend context.

Comment: Re NGrams: NGrams isn't perfect and even if so, our interpretation of the results is imperfect (there are things lost in collapsing a string search to a number). eg searching on single words can obscure that words can be polysemous, which may or may not be disambiguatable with context. So I tend to rely on only very large and consistent differences. Also I've noticed a weird artifact (or is it reality?) For many words there is this weird quick rise and level off in the 2010's ('buddy' has this feature).

Comment: My experiences are a bit biased, but I'm an American who's grandparents were first generation from England, and to me, 'chum' comes off as slightly masculine, working-class language that might be common in a pub. I'm unsure if text-frequency is as important here, as it isn't uncommon to have words that are used infrequently but are understood culturally due to a notable usage in media.

Comment: @DavidBradbury Yes, that's always a huge often over-looked limitation of NGrams, that it is only about written forms. That's why  sometimes we all (ELU questioners and answerers) have to rely on unsourceable information (introspection, voting) to judge answers.

Comment: @DavidBradbury - I tend to agree, but do recall that my father used to talk about his (and my) 'school chums'. Around 1990 I asked my teenage son about his 'pals' and he said 'Have you got trapped in a 1910 time warp?'

Comment: Chum makes me think of the old Adam West Batman. Everyone knows its meaning, but it's definitely old fashioned.

Comment: @Mitch:  I said as much on Meta, to you in fact, almost a decade ago: [What sources can be used to document usage, and isn't that highly context-dependent?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4237/what-sources-can-be-used-to-document-usage-and-isnt-that-highly-context-depend)

Comment: @smci Were the comments there sufficient to allay your concerns? If not, glad to join a chat you create if you'd like further explanation.

Comment: I grew up in England in 1960s and 1970s.  It was very common among all classes in spoken English then.  I'm pretty sure I heard women use it too, mostly private school types, but my memory is a bit hazy on that.  Don't know about current use.

Comment: There's a Hardy Boys book named [The Missing Chums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Missing_Chums) that was written in 1928 by a Canadian for a US publishing company. The title sounded very odd to me when I encountered the book in the 1980s. I think the word must have been more common in the US in the 1920s, though Google Ngram doesn't show a clear trend.